# Is it more proper to pull arm away from the fret to barre or use thumb to supply pressure to barre?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

I feel that when I barre I tend to use thumb to supply the pressure, however that sometimes cause strain in certain position, is this something I have to work through or is it more proper to supply pressure through arm?

Answer (score 2):

Using thumb to provide pressure on barre chords works, and it's what a lot of players use. BUT - it produces strain that's unnecessary particularly at the base of the thumb.

I advocate having hardly any thumb pressure at the back of the neck, in fact, barre chords can be played cleanly with no thumb touching the neck. It's a little impractical, though.

Using arm movement laterally, the fulcrum being the barring finger, works fine. Moving the elbow left/right, maybe slightly up/down, will help find a sweet spot.  But there's another balance point - the guitar against your body. By pulling backwards with the right arm, and backwards slightly with the left, pressure can be put on the barring finger.

Bear in mind that on a properly set up guitar, not a lot of pressure of any kind is going to be needed. Each of us has to work out balance points, and height of guitar, angle horizontally and angle against body all need addressing to find this balance. Which is dynamic, and will change whether we play single notes or strum chords.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize the importance of a well setup instrument. The first guitar I ever had hurt my hands within minutes, but I took it to a guitar tech, and when I got it back, neck was adjusted, the string height was set, the intonation was set, and I had no fret buzz. In one setup, it was a completely different playing experience, worth every nickel I spent. And I could play for hours with incredible ease. Any one having trouble with pressure related issues with their hands and playing, should have the instrument action checked and adjusted if necessary.

Comment: @skinnypeacock - absolutely! My first guitar hurt for the 18 months I had it. Couldn't have been set up, as it was a cheap acoustic. Unfortunately not everybody can pay for a decent set-up - around £60 in U.K. That's why I learned to do it myself !

Comment: @ Tim- I set up my own guitars these days myself, but I hesitate to recommend that early learners try this on their own without the necessary knowledge and understanding of how things work together.

Comment: @skinnypeacock- but doesn't everyone become almost instant experts using the internet these days. I think there's even a site for do-it-yourself brain surgery...

Comment: @Tim- I just imagine folks taking a wood rasp to their string grooves and a torque wrench to their truss  rod, catastrophic!

Answer (score 2):

Though using arm pressure can be a good thing, it is also important to be *able* to supply sufficient pressure using your thumb only when you need, because the amount of pressure you can exert with your fretting arm depends on how much you can hold the guitar in place with your other arm - and that may vary  depending on what strumming / picking technique you're using.

Of course you should still be trying to minimise that pressure - accurate hand positioning is important, and I find that thumb positioning is important for barre chords - I tend to find that a 'classical guitar' thumb position is the least fatiguing and stressful for barre chords. And as important as both of these things is guitar setup - a nice low action at the nut is very helpful.

It's good to try to get the guitar sufficiently high up on your body to reduce wrist and thumb stress when playing barre chords. It might not look as cool as a low slung rock style, but you can compensate for that by just acting cooler...

And of course it's also no bad thing to be able to fret a barre chord using only arm pressure too when possible - or use a mix of both. It's good to give your fretting hand as easy a time as possible, and using good technique and setup to minimise the pressure required helps whether you're using your arm or wrist.

Comment: 'A nice low action at the nut...'. That helps, but a nice low action all along is even better? I've worked on guitars with low action at nut, but > 6mm at 12th fret. Not a lot of help for barre chords!

Comment: @Tim you're right of course that a low action everywhere is good (for *most* playing styles), but the reason I highlight nut action (oo-er) is that the force required to push the string down is higher when you're very near the nut, due to the string being anchored there.

Comment: Interesting one, that. True, playing a barre F is seemingly more difficult than say, a D @ 10th fret. Whether the fret size comes into the equation - or arm stretch, or neck profile, not thought too much (yet!) but maybe there's a balance, and high action at, say, 12, means it's no easier. Food for thought!

Comment: @Tim just to make the point more obvious - if you try to press any string down 1mm from the nut, you can hardly do so at all. 1cm from the nut it's possible, but still hard. *At* the first fret, it should of course be eminently possible to fret the string, but you're still experiencing greater lateral tension because of the anchoring. It's the same reason that strings feel 'harder' when you strum or pick them near the bridge.

Comment: Not denying anything! Merely throwing out ideas for consideration...

Comment: @Tim Yep, all just ideas :) I guess the ideal from a fretting point of view is low action all the way, but the way (e.g.) the open string vibrates means that it's always going to displace furthest from around 12th fret to around where it's plucked , so you can't really have super low action at the 12th fret without risking fret buzz.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big advocate of "cheating" with my barre chords by [playing the bass notes with my thumb](http://www.streetmusician.co.uk/Assets/thumbbarchord.gif) when I'm at the lower frets. I might just have very large thumbs though...

General consensus is to avoid all methods which cause pain. If your guitar is set up correctly, your string height shouldn't be too great and barring shouldn't require much effort, assuming you have decent finger strength. Discomfort through lack of finger strength and stamina is normal and will pass eventually, but you should always stop playing when you get uncomfortable and nothing should be actually painful.

Comment: It is not cheating, it is "use of thumb".   :)  Why not use it if it is available and works!

Comment: You're not the first to use the thumb thus, and it works well for people bestowed with big/long thumbs. Keep going!

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use more thumb pressure.  It could actually put too much stress on your tendon and cause damage.  Also, it is not very good way to get the barre working for you.  I had the same problem before.

Instead, you would have to learn to use the weight of your arm.  Your thumb and fingers will be the anchor point and the weight of your arm will do the job.  If you relax your left hand, it will help to transfer the pressure evenly to all the string that your barre needs to cover.  Also, if you relax your shoulder, the weight of your arm will be transferred better to the strings and create more natural pressure.

If you use your thumb pressure to hold the barre, it will be difficult to move to different position, especially if you need to make a sudden position change.

Relax hand and shoulder, and learn to use the weight of your arm - that is how I was thought, and it worked!!

So, I guess my vote is "arm" with an additional tip - learn to use the weight of your arm.